# How do I get facebook like post to display image and description 

Tags: ruby-on-rails, facebook, facebook-like, fbconnect, fb-graph

I am using the facebook like button on a facebook app page. When a user likes a page only the url is posted to their wall.

I have tried the following

```
<meta property="og:title" content="my content" />
<meta property="og:image" content="my content"/>
<meta property="og:description" content="my content">
<meta property="og:type" content="product">
<meta property="og:url" content="my content">
<meta property="og:site_name" content="my content">
<meta property="fb:app_id " content="APPID">
```

alongside

```
    <meta name="title" content="mycontent" />
    <meta name="description" content="mycontent" />
    <link rel="image_src" type="image/jpeg" href="mycontent"/>
```

The app is written is rails. Has any one got a solution to this.

Comment: is `<meta property="og:image" content="my content"/>` a fully qualified URL? or is it a relative url?

Comment: Fully qualified it be...

Comment: accessible without authentication?

Comment: Works for me! You should provide an example or more details to get help.

Answer (score 1):

Don't forget the Open Graph namespace:

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html xmlns:fb="http://ogp.me/ns/fb#" lang="en" style="overflow:hidden;">
    <head prefix="og: http://ogp.me/ns# fb: http://ogp.me/ns/fb# <?php echo AppInfo::appNamespace(); ?>: http://ogp.me/ns/fb/<?php echo AppInfo::appNamespace(); ?>#">
        ...
```

Use the [Facebook Open Graph Debugger](https://developers.facebook.com/tools/debug) to check your site.